# Does Cocoa(Xamarin.Mac) applications support System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, mono, xamarin.mac

I have an app coded in GTK# that runs using Mono on Mac.Since its not possible to properly bundle the app with the Mono Runtime for Apple store.Im trying to migrate to Xamarin.mac(Cocoa).But my whole app uses System.Drawing.Graphics and stuff.Does Xamarin.Mac support this?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, use Xamarin.Mac Classic APIs.** This is 32bit only, and you can use Moni libraries there, with full System.Drawing assembly.

New Xamarin.Mac Unified APIs will produce 64bit app bundle, but System.Drawing doesn't fully work here.

Answer (score 0):

This library provides implementation of the System.Drawing API using Apple's CoreGraphics engine:

https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics

It works in Unified for Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin.iOS.